# Creation and annihilation form of hamiltonian to derive a relation between the ac current applied to the crystal and the oscillations of the crystal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, second-quantization

in the book "many-particle physics" by G.Mahan in piezoelectric subsection, it uses the second quantization formalism to derive the relation for hamiltonian of the electron-phonon interaction. so according to this formalism (that can be found anywhere on the literature):

Can we use the Creation and annihilation form of hamiltonian to derive a relation between the ac current applied to the crystal and the oscillations of the crystal (for example for quartz or any other piezoelectric material)?"

I know the answer is: "Yes"

But,does anyone know if we can calculate it analytically or we should use computer programming, please?

Comment: The general properties of a phonon spectrum can and are being derived in closed form in every beginners class in solid state physics. If you want to calculate a technically useful approximation of a phonon spectrum for a particular material, then you will typically do it using a computer. That's no different from any other area of applied physics.

Comment: what do you mean?!

Comment: Like with almost anything else in physics there are very few things that can be calculated in closed form well enough to match the experiment, so one is forced to apply the theory to set up numerical calculations to get realistic answers, in your case for the phonon spectra of real crystals (if you are interested in electrically driven excitations of lattice vibrations). Did I misunderstand the question?